Connection Lost with PostgreSQL Server - SSL Issue
I'm encountering an issue with PostgreSQL where I'm getting an SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected, resulting in a lost connection to the server.
Problem Description:
When attempting to connect to the PostgreSQL server, either through a client application or directly via psql, I receive the following error message:
error:
SSL SYSCALL error: EOF detected
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Succeeded.
anyone please help to resolve this issue.
Thanks.
I need solution for this to resolve this issue.

Look at the PostgreSQL server log at that time for more information.

Is there a firewall or network load balancer in between?
